# How to refer to a bar and remember that bar forever?

Tags: pine-script

[image]

How do you refer to the bar above and remember that bar forever? I want to take trades on my strategy script only after that specific bar. What expression do I need for `afterBar`?

```
afterBar = ?
longCondition = change(rsi(close,14))

if afterBar and longCondition
     strategy.entry()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code posted by PineCoders ["How can I detect a specific date/time?"](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time)

And modify it like this:

`afterBar  = savedOpen > 0 ? true : false`

Comment: Yup, this was what I was actually trying to do